# dynamically merge cells in .rdlc vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, rdlc

What i want to do is explained in the following image-
[image]

I want to dynamically merge rows at last 3 columns (InvoiceTotal, Paid, Due)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In designer view you can grouping data by InvoiceNo. One column with vertical span will be created automatically (InvoiceNo) then you have to add 4 columns of the same groups. I don't know if you can have 2 column with vertical span (InvoiceNo, Date) then details columns and then other 3 columns with vertical span (InvoiceTotal, Paid, Due).

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it or any other alternative technique?

Comment: Using HideDuplicates you can hide InvoiceTotal, Paid and Due if they have the same value of the previous row. But I don't find any techique to vertically center their value.

Comment: HideDuplicates won't be wise. It may cause hide value from other Invoice too. But if we can check duplicate within the same group, then it is possible.

Comment: I never used HideDuplicates but it seems "a powerful tool to make values appear only once per data set or group": http://glutenfreesql.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/ssrs-hide-duplicates/

Comment: This link seems to be useful. Hopefully it may solve my problem for the time being. Though, I also would like to merge cells vertically. Thanks.